# How to deploy maven multi-module spring boot to docker container

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, multi-module

I'm setting  up a multi-module maven project and trying to deploy it to docker a typical 3 layer project whit a separate container for a `MYSQL` DB.

[image: project tree]

I've been doing so research on the web and I came across the `docker-compose` a concept if I understand correctly with a config `YAML` file you can deploy each jar file into a different container and make them work together, ¿is this the only approach in my case?

Could I build one only `jar` file from the 3 modules and deploy it to the container?
In my case i don't need to treat each project as a separate micro-service.
On the other hand, I need docker compose because besides my `spring boot` project you need to run a container with a `MYSQL DB` and connect it to the  `spring-boot`.

I'm not sure how to approach this scenario, thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: Doesn't your web module depend on the others? Is there a separate api module?  I think you need to say more about your architecture.

Comment: yes it does,web depends on Domain and Domain depends on Persistence yes they are separated each project is a separate module,representing a layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse having n-tiers in your application with a micro-service architecture.

Micro-services are separate units of deployment and communicate among themselves over some sort of protocol (http, a message bus, something).  Calling a function in process (from one jar to another) is not that, and so your individual maven modules aren't candidates for being put in containers and orchestrated by docker-compose.

If your web app communicated with the Domain Layer via, say, a restful api, then you could use docker compose to spin up two separate containers.

But if, as is likely, your "api" is handled by controllers in the web app making in-process calls to your domain layer, you only have a single container to create and deploy.

There might still be good reasons to containerize your monolithic application. Perhaps it has complex OS dependencies and/or you want to deploy it to a PAAS like AWS Fargate or gCloud.

You might still want to use docker-compose as well, to deploy mysql in a container along side your web app.

Comment: if i understand correctly  just the fact you have 3 Jars doesn't mean you have to deploy them separately? the application is just a Spring rest-api nothing major so you suggest as long as I have dependencies between them, I'm ok if i deploy only the web module? the dependencies are set up as you said via maven linking the persistence to the domain layer and the web to the domain layer

Comment: yup. Containers aren't the solution for having jars talk to one another!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the concepts, I will try to deploy the web module and see what happens

Comment: on the other hand, I could include in the docker file maven and build the project in the container

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Robert, each jar/module does *not* equal a single Docker image (and thus container) in most cases.

I wanted to add that each boot application (i.e. each class with a main method) will likely end up in its own container (not always but it's a good rule of thumb). This is because each Docker image can have a single entrypoint, which is really just the command that executes to start the container. Thus each main method you create is a good candidate to put in its own container, because the `java` command can only execute one main method on startup.

Docker Compose is great for automating the startup of containers together, but it's just one of many tools that can do this ([docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/), [rancher](https://rancher.com/), and [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) being other tools you can look at). Keep in mind, however, that these are others are heavy duty, production quality services and likely overkill for simple dev or test setups. Docker Compose works great for cases where you don't need automated scaling, fault tolerance, complex security policies, secrets management, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to dockerize your multi-module maven project.

In this case, you need to dockerize your fat Jar from the module which contains your boot application `@SpringBootApplication` (e.g web) and not all the jar files from different modules. They will be automatically included as internal dependencies inside your main module (e.g web).

You can find in the end of [Optimized docker images for Spring Boot applications with layering feature](https://redamessoudi.com/optimized-docker-images-for-spring-boot-apps/) a section related to how to dockerize multi-module project.